# Customize equation numbering for Cases environment?

Tags: equations, numbering, cases

I want to use equation numbering like this
[image]

I tried like this but doesn't work

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\varlimsup_{r \to \infty} \dfrac{\log ^{+} n\left\{U_{k=1}^{N} \Omega\left(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r\right), f=0\right\}}{\log r}<\mu, &\text{if } \mu>0 \tag{2.5}\label{e2.5}\\ 
\varlimsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N} n\left(\Omega\left(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r\right), f=0\right)}{\log r}<+\infty, & \text{if } \mu=0,\tag{2.6}\label{e2.6}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: See the empheq package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution, based on `empheq` and `alignat`, to have full control on the spacing between the two alignment columns. Also some improvements (some  `left … \right` pairs are unnecessary here, and I preferred to replace the other ones with `\bigl … \bigr`). Last, the `U_{k=1}^N` coding  should be `\bigcup_{k=1}^N`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{2}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{alignat=2}
 & \varlimsup_{r \to \infty} \frac{\log ^{+} n\bigl\{\bigcup_{k=1}^{N} \Omega(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r), f=0\bigr\}}{\log r}<\mu,& \quad & \text{if } \mu>0 \label{eqn1}\\
%
 & \varlimsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} n\bigl(\Omega(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r), f=0\bigr)}{\log r}<+\infty, & & \text{if } \mu=0 \label{eqn2}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the `empheq` package, you can assign equation number inside cases.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace }]{align}
     &\varlimsup_{r \to \infty} \dfrac{\log ^{+} n\left\{U_{k=1}^{N} \Omega\left(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r\right), f=0\right\}}{\log r}<\mu,\quad && \text{if } \mu>0 \label{eqn1}\\
%      
    &\varlimsup_{r \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N} n\left(\Omega\left(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r\right), f=0\right)}{\log r}<+\infty,\quad && \text{if } \mu=0 \label{eqn2}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `{DispWithArrows}` of `witharrows`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{witharrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}<>[format=ll,fleqn]
\varlimsup\limits_{r \to \infty} \dfrac{\log ^{+} n\left\{U_{k=1}^{N} \Omega\left(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r\right), f=0\right\}}{\log r}<\mu,\quad & \text{if } \mu>0 \label{eqn1}\\
%      
\varlimsup\limits_{r \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N} n\left(\Omega\left(\theta_{k}+\varepsilon, \theta_{k+1}-\varepsilon ; r\right), f=0\right)}{\log r}<+\infty,\quad & \text{if } \mu=0 \label{eqn2}
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]